# How to preserve white spaces and new Lines

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xslt, pre

I have a table inside which i am using `<pre contenteditable="true">` where user can review and edit the data. I want to store the data which the user inputs in a var in Javascript.
As far as I am getting two problems here

1. I am not able to delete any input i.e. Backspace button is not working
2. The data which I am getting in the var of JS doesn't preserve new Lines.
   I am attaching my sample code. Thanks in advance!

`XSL`

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" >
    <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="//faml/response/mtcresponsedto/terms_conditons/tandcdto">
            <div class="carousel">
                <div class="frames">
                    <td style="padding-right: 10px">
                        <xsl:variable name="txn_desc">
                            <xsl:value-of select="termsandconditions"/>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <div>
                            <pre contenteditable="true">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$txn_desc"/>
                            </pre>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </div>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
</table>
```

`JS`

```
const pre = document.querySelector("pre");
const flag = pre.textContent;
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ref_xsl_el_preserve-space.asp  will this help ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but No. I am adding extra line but in JS var it is not preserving the new line...

Comment: you mean in `pre` ? also can you please put what is in `pre` ?

Comment: This is how i am getting the value in my var ```hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh<br><br><br>THE LEGAL AGREEMENTS SET OUT BELOW GOVERN YOUR USE OF THE ITUNES STORE, MAC APP STORE, APP ```. Can you suggest me a way to replace <br> with new line or something cz i dont want tag as i have to save this information database..

Comment: digged from a Q , is this what you are looking for ? `yourString.replace(/(<br>|<\/br>|<br \/>)/mgi, "\n");`

Comment: Thank you so much again i found this too and currently i am trying to include the regex expression in my xslt 1.0 cz currently it is showing error...I am also searching for the answer on stackoverflow only...

Comment: did you finally get through this ? hope you have